# Stop text jumping around in accordion

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've been working on an accordion element using react and tailwind but I'm not sure how to fix this problem where the text inside of the accordion shifts and jumps around when I trigger the transition.

[gif of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhxT6.gif)

```
                <div className={`flex bg-grey gap-6 transition-all duration-500 ${open ? "h-auto p-6" : "h-0 p-0 overflow-hidden"}`}>
                    <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2">
                        <img src={project.image} alt={`${project.title} Image`} />
                        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-2 text-lg text-white">
                            {project.tools.map((tool: string) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={tool} className="bg-red px-2 py-1 my-2">
                                        {tool}
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2 text-xl text-white gap-4">
                        <div className="flex flex-col bg-blue py-6">
                            <p className="font-bold text-center">
                                The What
                            </p>
                            <p className="text-justify text-lg px-6">
                                {project.what}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="bg-blue py-6">
                            <p className="font-bold text-center">
                                The So What
                            </p>
                            <div className="text-justify text-lg px-6">
                                <ul className="list-inside list-disc">
                                    {project.soWhat.map((item: string) => {
                                        return (
                                            <li key={item}>
                                                {item}
                                            </li>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Seems like there's padding getting applied to your accordion body when opening/active state. Check the CSS

Answer (score 0):

When it opens you change the padding here:
`${open ? "h-auto p-6" : "h-0 p-0 overflow-hidden"}`.

The change from `p-0` to `p-6` combined with the `transition-all` with a duration of 500ms is causing the behavior.

You might want to set `p-6` as the fixed value for the div (making it not conditional).

Or only transition height by replacing `transition-all` by `transition-[height]`, using height as [the arbitrary value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property#arbitrary-values).